# PDF file stored in BLOB is not displayed with the "Content-Length" response header

Tags: php, pdf, blob

The following example is meant for displaying a PDF file, when requested.

```
$sql = "SELECT file FROM file_upload WHERE id=:id and file_type in('pdf')";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['id']));

$query->bindColumn("file", $file, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);

$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
$mimeType = $finfo->buffer($file);

header("Content-type: $mimeType");
header('Content-Description: PDF document');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
//header('Content-Length: '.strlen($file));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0');

ob_clean();
flush();
echo $file;
```

The requested PDF file is displayed but when the following line is added,

```
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($file));
```

the browser does not display the requested PDF file. The browser issues a message.

[image]

What might be the reason? The length returned by `strlen()` does not appear to be the exact length. `strlen()` however, returns `451295` for an uploaed PDF file of size 506,296 bytes (about 495 KB).

Trying on recent versions of Google Chrome and Mozilla FireFox using PHP 5.4.

Comment: Perhaps you have the `mb` extension enabled? Try `mb_strlen($file, '8bit')`.

Comment: That extension is enabled. It also returns the same length as `strlen()` which causes the same problem -- no change.

Comment: It is working. I forgot to mention the second parameter. It returns the exact length `506296` for the specified file. Is there any alternative in case the `mb` extension is disabled in production?

Comment: Yes, you have to wrap the call in a condition. This is a common problem in libraries that (a) make use of string functions for byte manipulation and (b) have to deal with run-times that may, or may not, include `mb`. My answer should address how to support both versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have the `mbstring` extension enabled, the `strlen` function returns the length of the string in characters, not necesasrily as bytes. The workaround is to detect, at run-time, the extension situation and use the appropriate method.

One way to handle this is a function that always returns bytes, regardless of the presence or absence of the `mb` extension. Example:

```
if (2 & ini_get('mbstring.func_overload')) {
    function bytes($string) {
        return mb_strlen($string, '8bit');
    }
} else {
    function bytes($string) {
        return strlen($string);
    }
}
```

You can of course rewrite that to put the condition inside the function, instead of having a conditional function. That incurs a run-time penalty for a constant check, so it's more efficient to have conditional functions. Depends upon your needs, though.

You may also use a third-party library. The example above is taken from [haldayne/boost](https://packagist.org/packages/haldayne/boost). Disclaimer: I'm the author of haldayne/boost.

Comment: What does this conditional statement mean, `2 & ini_get('mbstring.func_overload')` (sorry, coming from Java environment)?

Comment: The `mbstring` extension can modify three different categories of functions -- mail functions, string functions, and ereg functions -- depending upon configuration. `strlen` (and its `str*` friends) are affected only when the `mbstring` extension is configured to override the string functions. Thus you can have `mbstring` extension enabled, but not have the string functions affected. This conditional checks that. See also [the mbstring docs on function overrides](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php).